# Cherry-picked commits have different hashes

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-cherry-pick, git-cherry

Say I do `git log branch-A..branch-B`, I get a list of commits that are in `branch-B` but not in `branch-A`. I can also get a list of commits in `branch-A` but not in `branch-B` by reversing the order.

Almost every commit into `branch-A` is cherry-picked into `branch-B`, however I noticed that `git log` shows commits that have been cherry-picked. In particular I notice that the commit hash of the cherry-picked commit in `branch-B` is different from the one that is in `branch-A`. Does someone know why this could happen? If so how to perform the diff so that it does not capture these false positives?

Comment: Use `git cherry` or any of the `cherry*` options to `git log`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In particular I notice that the commit hash of the cherry-picked commit in branch-B is different from the one that is in branch-A

Of course.

git commit store the **parent** as part of the metadata calculating the SHA-1.
Since the parent is different the SHA-1 will be different as well.

[image]

Comment: So is there a way to compare two branches factoring this into the equation?

Comment: You can use `git log aa..bb` or `git log ^aa bb`

Comment: Well I have been doing that and the cherry-picks show up